# react-native-dropdown-picker scroll inside another scroll is not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview, react-native-dropdown-picker

Drop down scroll is not working inside another scroll in react-native-dropdown-picker

I already tried giving

```
listMode="SCROLLVIEW"
    scrollViewProps={{
      nestedScrollEnabled: true,

 }}
```

to the  as a prop. But still not working.

here is my code

```
<SafeAreaView edges={['right', 'left', 'bottom']} style={styles.container} >
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={[globalStyles.contentWrap, { marginBottom: 16, height: 1000 }]}>
                        <View>

                            <View style={{ zIndex: 10 }}>

                                <DropDownPicker
                                    listMode="SCROLLVIEW"
                                    placeholder="Select your restaurant"
                                    style={{
                                        borderColor: Colors.borderColor,
                                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                                        borderWidth: 1,
                                        paddingHorizontal: 12,
                                        paddingVertical: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 12 : 6,
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        borderRadius: 5,
                                        marginTop: 8,
                                        marginBottom: 16,
                                    }}
                                    dropDownContainerStyle={{
                                        borderColor: Colors.borderColor,
                                        color: Colors.black1,
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        borderRadius: 5,
                                    }}
                                    placeholderStyle={{
                                        color: '#696969',
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                    }}
                                    textStyle={{
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                    }}
                                    dropDownMaxHeight={240}
                                    open={open}
                                    value={value}
                                    items={items}
                                    setOpen={setOpen}
                                    setValue={setValue}
                                    setItems={setItems}
                                    schema={{
                                        label: 'name',
                                        value: 'id',
                                    }}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>

                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
```

The scroll bar shows in the dropdown but its not scrollable.
here is a reference image..

[image: here is a image]

Comment: I think you need to move the dropdown outside of the scrollView, because it's not detecting the target scrollable item (I mean the scrollView or the drop down)

Comment: There are many other input fields in the screen, so moving it outside wont fix the problem , The  from should be scrollable,

Comment: Add "nestedScrollEnabled={true}" property to the internal ScrollView (dropdown) and check it

Comment: @Jamal  Tried giving  nestedScrollEnabled={true} to the <DropDownPicker> component not fixed

Answer (score 1):

As per their official documentation, you can't have a  inside scrollview.

***Notes#***

> The **FlatList** component shouldn't be nested inside **ScrollView**
> or you'll come across the VirtualizedLists should never be nested
> inside plain ScrollViews warning. If this happens to you and you only
> have a few items, consider using the **SCROLLVIEW** mode. Otherwise
> you have to use the **MODAL** mode.

See this link:
https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/advanced/list-modes

Comment: Tried giving  nestedScrollEnabled={true} to the <DropDownPicker> component not fixed

Comment: @JeesmonJoy sorry, I have updated the answer. please check the link

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing issues with the dropdown picker not scrolling when used within a `react-native-modal` modal. To fix try putting `propagateSwipe` prop as true onto the modal and it should now allow your picker to be scrollable

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue with nested scrolling. Use ScrollView of react-native-gesture-handler with nestedScrollEnabled={true}. It works better in android. You can also patch react-native-dropdown-picker for that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a `ScrollView` with a `Flatlist` inside, to solve this I added the property `nestedScrollEnabled={true}` to `FlatList`, like:

```
<FlatList
    nestedScrollEnabled={true}
```

It worked for me, but the device keeps giving a warning. So even though it works, I don't know if it's the best solution

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles on this, editing the nodemodules for `react-native-dropdown-picker` fixed this for me.

See this comment from the package owner https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker/issues/647#issuecomment-1462990359

There's a 5.4.7-beta.1 version you can install if you don't want to maintain a patch with [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that giving flexDirection: row to the parent will make the dropdown picker scroll not to work